# Bash scripts and defining variables

Tags: bash, scripts

when i launch my `bash` script:

```
$ ./mybashscript.sh
```

How do I define variables with in it if i want to be able to append values for them in the execution of the above command? ie, how do i declare variables day,month and year in my .sh file if i were using it to record an entry,

```
$ ./EventDateLog.sh -day=17 -month=2 year=2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with short name variables the easiest way I see would be using `getopts` like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while getopts :d:m:y: FLAG; do case $FLAG in

    d) # set day
      DAY=$OPTARG
      ;;

    m) # set month
      MONTH=$OPTARG
      ;;

    y) # set year
      YEAR=$OPTARG
      ;;

    \?) # unrecognized option - show help
    echo "your help message here"
    exit 0
      ;;   

 esac
done


# the rest of your program here handling your variables
echo "$DAY" "$MONTH "$YEAR"
```

#### Example

```
$ ./EventDateLog.sh -d 17 -m 2 -y 2019
17 2 2019
```